# Revert to default behavior for physical back button

Tags: android, cordova, reactjs

I have a `Cordova` app made with `ReactJS`. When on the homepage I would like the back button to suspend the app (default behavior) and when not on the home page I would like to have my custom implementation of history to take over. In the `deviceready` event handler I added

```
document.addEventListener( 'backbutton', onBackButtonKeyDown.bind(this), false);
```

The implementation of `onBackButtonKeyDown` looks like this (removed some stuff to make the code clearer):

```
function onBackButtonKeyDown(e) {
    if(!SomeStore.isMainMenuClosed) {
        e.preventDefault();
        historyButtonActions.raiseBackButtonClickedEvent();
    }
};
```

I also tried adding an `else` block with `return false;`. In all cases the default behavior is not triggered. While Googling I saw some suggestions to use `navigator.app.exitApp();`, but I don't want to exit the app. I want the `Home` intent to take over and for the app to suspend like the default functionality works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up side stepping the issue by adding and removing the custom handler from the `backbutton` event as needed. Once the handler is removed, the default behaviour returns.